# conversion string to type date is not valid error in windows 7 professional

Tags: vb.net, date, windows-7

Hi guys.
This code works fine. There's no problem, after I published it and installed to different machines. But when I tried to install it to a pc having windows 7 professional OS it keeps on displaying the error.

heres my code:

```
 If CGO_LegalDataGridView.Rows.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To Me.CGO_LegalDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
            If CGO_LegalDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = Nothing Then Exit Sub
            If DateValue(CGO_LegalDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value) < DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now) Then
                Me.CGO_LegalDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(0).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
                Me.CGO_LegalDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(1).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
                Me.CGO_LegalDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Style.ForeColor = Color.DarkGray
            End If
        Next i
```

The function of this code is to make the font color of each row color gray when duedate column is less than the date today... Is it the OS of the computer might be the issue why theres always a error `"conversion "10/10/13" to type date is not valid"` for example.

Comment: Please add the complete error. From this we could only guess, that it is a culture-related problem or a DateTime format related issue.

Comment: How are you storing the date in the database? As a String?

Comment: @Serv "Conversion from string "" to type 'date' is not valid"

Comment: @JackPettinger as string thats the reason why i put "datevalue" first before the column having the string....  it works fine to my pc and other pc but theres one computer having this error..

Comment: This is because of the regional setting of the PC. To avoid issues like this, you should save it as a date, not a string. This is not sortable, it takes up more space in your database, and it is slower to query. Why are you saving it as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response guys I appreciate it. I found out the problem its not on query or datatype of the date column. Its because the default date format of that computer is changed and different to the common format (M/d/yyy) so I changed it on the "control panel" then "Region and Language" then "Format" I set all the date format to the default English (united states) format..

Comment: That is what Steve stated in his comment, and suggested you save it in as a Date not a string which would eliminate you having to change the PC's regional settings